# How can I append to an array in NumPy without flattening the arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I append two arrays in NumPy without flattening?

I tried changing axis.

```
>>> h = np.array([])
>>> g = np.array([2,4])
>>> i = np.array([6,9])
>>> np.append(h,g)
array([2., 4.])
>>> h = np.append(h,g)
>>> h
array([2., 4.])
>>> np.append(h,i)
array([2., 4., 6., 9.])
>>> np.append(h,i, axis=0)
array([2., 4., 6., 9.])
>>> np.append(h,i, axis=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 5617, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
numpy.exceptions.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
>>>
```

I was expecting:

`h = [[2,4],[6,9]]`

Comment: Check `np.vstack(h, i)`

Comment: `np.append` with axis is just a call to `no.concatenate`.- as shown by the error message.  Dimensions must match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [np.vstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy-vstack),

```
np.vstack((h, i))
```

**Output:**

```
np.array([[2,4],[6,9]])
```